# How to Disable Changing the Installed Theme in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I developed my own WordPress theme for my client!.
If he changes the theme from outside, he will lose my theme.
I want to disable him from changing Wordpress theme from mine theme.
How can I Disable it?[image] is there any way by editing the Wordpress files?

Comment: An easy way if that's a possibility: give him a user with *Editor* capabilities only and keep *Admin* for yourself. Otherwise, check https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page

Comment: After, If he wants to add another user, Admin role is required! :(

Comment: remove submenu page will only hide Themes from the submenu. When we go to /theme.php we can access simply

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But most users won't try to go to `/theme.php` if it's not in the menu. Anyway, a proper method would be to create a custom role and give it the required capabilities. This can be done by coding or with a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-roles-and-capabilities/)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove theme submenu using following code. Add below code in your theme's functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'adjust_the_wp_menu', 999 );
function adjust_the_wp_menu() 
{
    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'themes.php' ); 
}
```

***Restrict admin to open file***

```
add_action( 'current_screen', 'this_screen' );
function this_screen() 
{
     $current_screen = get_current_screen();
     if( $current_screen ->id === "themes" ) 
     {
        wp_die("You don't have access to this page.");       
     }
}
```

Comment: this will only remove that theme from menu list but when we go to wp-admin/themes.php we can access it

Comment: Normally as a developer we keep this file accessible but still if you want to remove to access using url even then check my answer again. I mentioned that thing.